# FMS Standard Dash Display not reported on SAE J1939 data link

Tags: can

I have a listen-only device plugged into SAE J1939 data link in Volvo FH440 (2014). So far I managed to collect HRLFC, TCO1 and some other, but no Dash Display (PGN 0xFEFC). I collected data in stationary conditions (no vehicle motion, ignite on), so far I had no opportunity to collect them during motion, but judging by the fact that other PGNs are reported normally I would expect this one too.

Is there any special condition under which this PGN (0xFEFC) is reported on the bus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been working with similar model Volvos, but with the body builder module output
I had a quick look and DD is part of the FMS standard, however volvo doesn't always broadcast all of the values they specify, (the FM/FH seem to have 3 different groupings of what is available with no clear reasoning why)

[image]

[image]

I can confirm for you that that value should be broadcast on the body builder module output pins provided it is switched on, P1BNY = 2, as well as the other parameters you have mentioned.

On plug BBM-B1 pin 29 is CAN kigh, pin 30 in CAN low.

[image]

Comment: What is 1.4 in content table then? BTW particularly what I want from DD is fuel level 1. Also I have a FMS standard PDF found on the web which contains DD so I am bit lost now. Could you comment on that?

Comment: Sorry, blind, when I searched "DD" it did not appear, my copy has somehow broken that into "D D", I have noticed that based on age the FM/FH volvos seem to present 3 different groupings of what can data is available with no clear reasoning why, have added the definition for the volvo DD message as a just in-case

Comment: No prob. So my problem still holds because the spec is right: I should be looking for 0xFEFC, yet I am not receiving it on the bus. Could you point to me where to look for P1BNY? I do not see it in body builder instructions.

Comment: It's on the portal under the bbm can messages document, in the very first few pages, where it runs you through the list of options you can switch on. Your after the ones for a V4 volvo. The BBM can is off by default. Volvo switch it on by updating that setting.

Comment: Hey it's been some time since last update, but this side project of mine is still in development. I am connected to BBM-B1 and I am able to read some of the PGN s but the dash display 0xFEFC is missing. Is there a change that Volvo is reporting fuel level under a different PGN? You previously  mentioned something about 3 groupings, what about them?

Comment: did you receive notification about comment? Just confirming :)

Comment: I've looked into what vehicles I have pulling data from that point, without spending much more time on it, it seems only 82 of 103 vehicles are receiving fuel level percentage. which comes from that parameter, however I never worked out quite what made the difference, its not year model (all V4), or FH / FM, so my leading guess right now is some other option stops the dash from broadcasting it.

Comment: OK. I guess based on comments I will accept the answer in the moment. Thank you. One last question. Do you know if there is any other source of information (other parameter) that I can retrieve fuel level from? I looked through the SAE1971 docs and haven't found anything interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You will not find fuel level using DD. It is broadcast on J1939 using proprietary ID 0x18FFBF11.

You can also obtain the same value closer to the source at J2284 chassis net ID 0x12FFA320